# Are there any tools to edit the initrd file in Windows?

Tags: windows, system-installation, initrd

Currently I am running on a Windows machine. I would like to modify a Linux ISO before installing it. For this I need to change a package inside initrd. Is there a way to do this from Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can't modify an ISO image: this filesystem is designed to be read-only. You'll have to extract the image, modify the files, then build a new image. I'm sure there's software to do that on Windows, but I don't know which.

You can try manipulating the files with the [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) utilities. An initrd is a filesystem image, typically ext2, for which there is no good support on Windows. However these days, the file is likely to be an [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) instead, even if it's called `initrd-SOMETHING`, and an initramfs is a [cpio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) archive which can be manipulated with the `cpio` command in Cygwin or other Windows ports of Linux utilities.

Unless you know exactly what you're doing, this is likely to be a difficult process involving trial and error. I recommend that instead, you install the same Linux distribution in a virtual machine ([VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is convenient for this use case), and use the tools provided by that distribution to modify its boot image. This is very likely to be the easiest and least time-consuming method.

Comment: I know exactly what to do under a Linux installation. Just being lazy+adventurous and trying to do it under Windows. Anyway, oddly enough, cygwin seems to not recognise cpio `$ cpio
-bash: cpio: command not found` and `$ man cpio
No manual entry for cpio`

The vbox route is probably not the best choice for me because I need to replace the network driver. And that works just fine under vbox but not on an actual install. Maybe I need to take the long route to this one..

Comment: @Yogesch You need to install it as a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MC for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcwin32/)

***Note***: I have never tried it

Comment: No, but I had a quick look and it might just be what I'm looking for. I'll let you know if it works :-)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work.